# Write a program that prints out the sum of the numbers in the file

Tags: python, text

I have written the following program that reads numbers from a file.  I can assume that each line contains only a single floating number.

```
filename = input("Please enter your file name: ")
sum_number = 0

openthefile = open(filename, "r")
for i in openthefile:
    sum_number = sum_number + float(i)
    print("The sum of your numbers is", sum_number)
```

I gave it the file named `number.txt` which contains:

```
8.0
-2.5
100.0
6.5
```

and my program printed out:

```
The sum of your numbers is 8.0
The sum of your numbers is 5.5
The sum of your numbers is 105.5
The sum of your numbers is 112.0
```

But, I just needed the last line to be printed out.

Comment: move your `print` statement out of the loop!

Answer (score 2):

`sum_number` is an int, and when you do `[i]` you're creating a single element list containing `i`, so that error is to be expected.

Just change:

```
sum_number = sum_number + [i]
```

to

```
sum_number = sum_number + float(i)
```

And you should be fine.  Note, not only do you need to not wrap `i` in a list, but you also need to convert it to a float, otherwise you'll get a similar but different error:

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str'
```

**Edit** per comments, the entire code would be:

```
filename = input("Please enter your file name: ")
sum_number = 0

openthefile = open(filename, "r")
for i in openthefile:
    sum_number = sum_number + float(i)

print("The sum of your numbers is", sum_number)
```

Comment: @kunjimamu sorry, I updated the code shortly after I posted -- if you refresh you should see that `int(i)` became `float(i)`.

Comment: it is not giving me the sum. it is just printing out each line from the file

Comment: @kunjimamu you had sneaky spaces in your variable name (or I somehow ended up with them) -- make sure they're not there.

Comment: Removed the space, but still it is printing out each line from the file.

Comment: THE file name that i entered is number.txt which contains some numbers. And the program printed out:                                               The sum of your numbers is 8.0
The sum of your numbers is 5.5
The sum of your numbers is 105.5
The sum of your numbers is 112.0

Comment: Can you edit your question to include your updated code?  I'll edit my answer to include the entire code.

Comment: I just needed the final total which is 112.0

Comment: @kunjimamu ahhh -- see my most recent edit -- just "outdent" the last line that has the `print` function on it.

Answer (score 2):

use the `with` keyword, it makes file handling safe. Type cast each number to `float` like so:

```
sum = 0
with open("foo.txt", 'r') as fin:
    for line in fin:
        sum+=float(line)
print sum
```

Content of foo.txt

```
2.37
4.35
6.27
```

## Output:

> 12.99

## Edit:

Same code without using the `with` keyword:

```
f = open("foo.txt", 'r')
lines = f.read().splitlines()
f.close()

sum = 0
for l in lines:
    sum+=float(l)

print sum
```

Comment: is there any other way? I am asking it because I did not learn about the 'with' command.

Comment: it is not too late to learn `with` keyword :). let me see if i can quickly do it with your method itself.